# React ForwardRef + Children + Props + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I know that at a first glance this question seems to be a dupe, but I searched everywhere and cannot fit the answers into my use case.

Basically, I'm trying to forward a ref some levels deep until I found a DOM element and use this ref to access the element props on the higher-level component.

The `Level2` component should be able to:

- Receive its own props (greet)
- Receive children
- Receive a ref and forward it (btnRef)

This is snippet can explain it better what I'm trying to do

```
interface Level2Props {
  greet: string;
}

const Level2 = React.forwardRef(
  (props: Level2Props, ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    return (
      <section>
        <button ref={ref} onClick={() => alert(props.greet)}>
          Click Me
        </button>
        {props.children}
      </section>
    );
  }
);

export default function App() {
  const [btnRef, setBtnRef] = React.useState();

  return (
    <section>
      <Level2 greet="Hello from level 2" ref={setBtnRef}>
        <div>Children from 1</div>
      </Level2>
      {btnRef && `Text from button: ${btnRef.innerHTML}`}
    </section>
  );
}
```

I'm having 3 problems here:

1. It says that `props.children` doesn't exist
2. I cannot pass `ref={btnRef}`, it says the types aren't compatible.
3. It says `btnRef.current.innerHTML` doesn't exist on type `never`

I tried everything on the `const Level2 = ...` line, but nothing seems to work (the code actually works, but the typings are wrong)

**edit:** to better illustrate the situation I've created an [external sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/forwardref-children-ts-usestate-n6r7z7?file=/src/App.tsx). The mentioned errors are on lines *15*, *26* and *29*, respectively

edit 2: using useState in the example instead of useRef, the [old sandbox is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/forwardref-children-ts-ck51bq?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

React Engine renders with a top-down approach, so you can't expect it to render a child and to rerender a parent with a child's data that is rendered later, unless child does not trigger a re-render of the parent itself.
So in your case you must set your node in a React state.
https://codesandbox.io/s/forwardref-children-ts-forked-zdielk?file=/src/App.tsx

You must be careful and call node update only if node !== prevRef , or you are going to have an infinite loop since the child render will trigger a rerender of Parent and then of child itself, and so on. You could also try to wrap your child in a React.memo() wrapper, to avoid further re-renders if props don't change.

*I'm not sure that it's a good idea to compare two DOM nodes as a control `node !== prevRef.current, but it works for the sake of the example simplicity`*

Comment: Yes, you are right about the render flow, actually I've simplified things in my example, but in my real use case I'm using state to track the refs, so the code is working as expected, except for the typings :-/  Anyway, I definitely try the memo tip

Comment: Just to clarify, in my use case I'm rendering some markers on a map, and when a click a marker I need a reference to it in order to access its coordinates and center the map. The marker list is an array in the state, but since I have a custom marker that wraps the "raw" marker, I need to forward the ref to it

Comment: I should see the code in the exact case, but i don't think you need ref at all in your use case.